# RESOLVED: What is the default Androd icon when making a homescreen shortcut?

Tags: android, web-applications, icons, shortcut, homescreen

I'd like folks to be able to make a shortcut of my web page to their homescreen, but I'm struggling to customize the icon (I use Android).

When I do it, creating a homescreen shortcut works, however it creates a generic "M" icon (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKjvG.jpg). The left image is the M icon, the right image is what I'd prefer and exists on the server as icon.png.

Ostensibly, it's defaulting to the "M" icon because I'm using the subdomain of br549.mywebcommunity.org and it generates the M for "mywebcommunity.org"

Is there a way to bypass this default icon action to one that I can set in the subdomain?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, got it to work.

[This page helped](https://mooretechsolutions.com/create-an-iphone-or-android-home-screen-icon-for-your-website/) with the code, also, the apple-touch-icon.png file had to be in the root directory. Placing it in an "images" folder didn't work for some reason.

Anyway, when I add an icon to home screen of my Anroid phone, it adds the custom icon. Problem resolved.